# SpringBoot: activate log4j2 ScriptSupport

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I use log4j2 for logging my SpringBoot application. I activate the yml file by 'config.classpath=log4j2.yml'.

I would like to use a ScriptFilter within the Log4j2 configuration. To do this, the corresponding language (e.g. groovy or javascript) must be activated in the current log4j2 version by the system property log4j2.Script.enableLanguages. Therefore I start the application with -Dlog4j2.Script.enableLanguages=javascript. Unfortunately, the error message appears when using the ScriptFilter: ERROR Script support is not enabled

Apparently the Log4j2 property is not being edited correctly. How can script support for log4j2 be activated within a SpringBoot application?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can add "log4j2.component.properties" file to your classpath, and put this content:

```
log4j2.Script.enableLanguages=javascript
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#system-properties

log4j2.component.properties has highest priority, when log4j2 starting, in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize()` function, PropertiesUtil.getProperties().getStringProperty("log4j2.Script.enableLanguages") cannot read environment variables or springboot config file, such as application.yaml